# VueJs not sending data via Inertia to Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have question it seems like when I try to send some data via Inertia I dont recieve any in Laravel for some reason any suggestion? Can it have to do something with the fact that the object is proxy object ?
Here are some images:

[dd() in php controlelr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWvbe.png)

[console.log() of the object before beeing sent via Inertia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVkzZ.png)

[Code of how I send the data + the console log right before sending it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrKfM.png)

UPDATE:

This is how I add page object to array of pages:

```
this.Pages.push({
            "name": "Untitled",
            "icon": "home",
            "order": order,
            "sections": [],
            "DisplayName":true,
            "Banner":"Medium",
            "Published":"Published",
            "DisplayLogo":true,
            "media":{
                'BackgroundImage': null,
                'LogoImage': null,
                'BackgroundImageHeight': null,
                'LogoImageHeight': null,
                'BackgroundImageStyle': {
                    "value": []
                },
                "LogoImageStyle": {
                    "value": []
                },
            }
        });
```

This is my inertia form:

```
        saveForm: {           
            applications: [],
        },
```

This is whole save() method:

```
 Save() {
        if(this.localProduct.translation.applications.mobile_label[this.currentMobileLabel] != undefined){
            if(this.localProduct.translation.applications.mobile_label[this.currentMobileLabel].data == undefined){
                this.localProduct.translation.applications.mobile_label[this.currentMobileLabel] = {
                    "Pages": this.Pages,
                    "media": this.media,
                    "name": this.localProduct.translation.applications.mobile_label[this.currentMobileLabel].name,
                    "active": this.localProduct.translation.applications.mobile_label[this.currentMobileLabel].active,
                };
            }
            else{
                this.localProduct.translation.applications.mobile_label[this.currentMobileLabel] = {
                    "Pages": this.Pages,
                    "media": this.media,
                    "name": this.localProduct.translation.applications.mobile_label[this.currentMobileLabel].name,
                    "active": this.localProduct.translation.applications.mobile_label[this.currentMobileLabel].active,
                    "data" : this.localProduct.translation.applications.mobile_label[this.currentMobileLabel].data,
                };
            }
        }    
        this.saveForm.applications = toRaw(this.localProduct.translation.applications);
        
        console.log(this.saveForm);

        Inertia.post(this.route(`product.translations.applications`,{translation: this.localProduct.translation.id}),this.saveForm);
    },
```

The applications should be array, the mobile_label should be also array.As it is.

!!!IMPORTANT ALSO!!!
All of this code worked before the project started to shift to vue js 3 and I suppose many libraries had to be updated/exchanged for others.

Comment: please dont use image links.  image links can eventually break, plus some answers may need to include some of your code and no one likes transcribing code from images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who's having same problem check your array/object assiging to your variables there could be the mistake like in mine I fixed mine with this:

```
        this.saveForm.applications = toRaw(this.localProduct.translation.applications);
        var fixed = Object.assign({},this.localProduct.translation.applications);
        Inertia.post(this.route(`product.translations.applications`,{translation: this.localProduct.translation.id}),fixed);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Inertia's documentation](https://inertiajs.com/forms) the first parameter expected when using `Inertia.post()` is a URL.  Does all of `` this.route(`product.translations.applications`,{translation: thislocalProduct.translation.id}) `` return a URL?

Comment: Yes, otherviwse I would not be able to recieve the dd() that happens in the specific endpoint pointing to specific controller that has the dd().

Comment: ok.  you'll need to post more codes (please not as screenshots).  your console.log says `applications` is Array(0) but then it has an object property called `mobile_label` so is `applications` an Array or Object?  it's strangely acting as both.  will need to see a lot more of your `<script>` code. how you're creating these objects and arrays, how you're making them reactive, how you're modifying them, etc.

Comment: So the applications should be array of objects. I am gonna add some additional code to the original post.